# Dataframe Replace Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am currently trying to replace a set of str values with a int value in python for my Dataframe. The DataFrame has over 200 columns, with columns such as Age_Range, Car_Year, Car_Count, Home_Value, Supermarket_Spend_Per_week, Household_Income etc.

I have answers (in columns) that begin with a. b. c. d. e. f. for the different responses.

For example a. Under $20k, b. $20 to $30k, c. $30 to $50k .. etc.

I have read through the wiki and know how to replace with word boundary etc. But I am wanting to replace any occurrence that begins with a with the value 1, b with the value 2, etc.

How would I write this for my Dataframe? All the regex functions i try end up with a invalid syntax

I currently have

```
income
h. No Answer
f. $100 to $150k
c. $30 to $50k
b. $20 to $30k
b. $20 to $30k
c. $30 to $50k
h. No Answer
```

of which i want to transform to

```
income
8
5
3
2
2
3
7
```

Being an integer will allow me to graph the results easier and search for relationships between columns.

Comment: What have you tried? and just give the input and output you expected should be more specified, honestly I don't quite follow your question description.

Comment: Shouldn't `No Answer` be 8? - eg, I'd expect: `[8, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 8]`... Although, if there's no `g`, then I suppose `7` makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex here, just create a lookup table and apply to your DataFrame's column based on that column's first character, eg:

```
df['income'] = df['income'].apply(lambda L, rep={c:i for i,c in enumerate('abcdefh', 1)}: rep[L[0]])
```

Which gives you: `[7, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 7]`

To apply this to all columns, then loop over the columns:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda L, rep={c:i for i,c in enumerate('abcdefh', 1)}: rep[L[0]])
```

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, but I have 40+ columns with responses similar to this, which is why I am wanting to modify the whole dataframe, not just a column

Comment: @Tobias121 then just apply it to all relevant columns? Could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28937033/edit) your question to clarify exactly what you do have... ?

Comment: the dataset has over 200 columns which is why I was trying to find a Regex expression that would allow any a to become 1 b to become 2 etc for the purposes of graphing and analysis.

Comment: @Tobias121 do **all** the columns in the DF require that same replacement? (as `Age_Range` looks like it should be a different lookup / none at all etc...)

Comment: All answers in the dataset start with a. b. c. d. e. f. and require the same replacement.

Comment: @Tobias121 updated answer to do a simple loop over each column... I think that's what you're after

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way of achieving your goal:

```
>>> re.sub(r"^([abcdef])", lambda x: str(ord(x.group(0))-ord('a')), "b. US$blah blabh")
'1. US$blah blabh'
```

What it does is "match either of the characters 'a' through 'f' at the beginning of a string and substitute it with the string representation of the offset of that character with respect to the letter 'a'". Repeat for every line of text.

With a bit of extra plumbing you could get rid of the rest of the line of input; it's a bit unclear what you want as output.

Comment: I am trying to modify the alphabet characters to ordinal numbers for the purposes of graphing on a large scale. Hence why I am trying to transform the abcdefg responses with 12345678.